# Latex Figure for Deep Reinforcement Learning

Tags: tikz-pgf

is there a way to produce the following diagram

[image]

by modifying the code below (tikzpicture)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\def\layersep{3cm}
\def\nodeinlayersep{1.5cm}


\begin{document}

        \def\layersep{3cm}
        \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, 
            text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
        \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex]
    \def\nodeinlayersep{1.5cm}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[ node distance = 7em, auto, thick]
        \node[block](Agent) {Agent};            
        \node [block, below of=Agent] (Environment) {Environment};    
                    %\node [block, right of=PEnvironment] (MEnvironment) {M Env};         
        \path [line] (Agent.0) --++ (7em,0em) |- node [near start]{$a_t$} (Environment.-10);
        \path [line] (Environment.200) --++ (-7em,0em) |- node [near start] 
                        { \rotatebox{90}{$s_t \rightarrow s_{t+1}$}} (Agent.165);
        \path [line] (Environment.180) --++ (-5.25em,0em) |- node [near start, right] 
                        {\rotatebox{90}{$r_t \rightarrow  r_{t+1}$}} (Agent.185);
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[
               shorten >=1pt,->,
               draw=black!50,
                node distance=\layersep,
                every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
                neuron/.style={circle, fill=gray!25, minimum size=17pt, inner sep=0pt},
                input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=gray!10},
                hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=gray!20},       
                output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=gray!30},
                annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
            ]

            % Draw the input layer nodes
            \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
            % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
                \node[input neuron] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {$x_\y$};

            % Draw the hidden layer nodes
            \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
                \path[yshift=0cm]
                    node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {$f(z_\y)$};

            % Draw the output layer node
            %\node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:$\hat{y}$}, right of=H-3] (O) {};
            \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:}, right of=H-2] (O) {$h_{\hat{w},\hat{b}}(x)$};

            % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
            % hidden layer.
            \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
                \foreach \dest in {1,...,3}
                    \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

            % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
            \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
                \path (H-\source) edge (O);

            % Annotate the layers
            \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1.5cm] (hl) {Hidden Layer ($l=2$)};
            \node[annot,left of=hl] {Input Layer ($l=1$)};
            \node[annot,right of=hl] {Output Layer ($l=3$)};
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Once the above code is executed, two networks appear side by side. It'd be nice if I could place the one depicted on the right inset inside the one on the left, specifically inside the box labelled Agent.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand one of the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages and libraries you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: @Andrew thanks, updated the code (and instructions) based on your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason I had a very similar code on my hard disk which I changed slightly and post here so that there is some answer. If it does not solve the problem completely it may at least be a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
   neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=2,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

% The command \DrawNeuronalNetwork has a list as argument, each entry is a
% layer. each entry has the form 
%  Layer name/number of nodes/color/missing node/label/symbolic number
% where
% * layer name is, well,  the name of the layer
% * number of nodes is the number of neurons in that layer (including the missing neuron)
% * color is the color of the layer
% * missing node denotes the index of the missing neuron
% * label denotes the label of the layer
% * symbolic number denotes the symbol that indicates how many neurons there are
% * node content
\newcommand{\DrawNeuronalNetwork}[2][]{
\xdef\Xmax{0}
\foreach \Layer/\X/\Col/\Miss/\Lab/\Count/\Content [count=\Y] in {#2}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\Xmax}{max(\X,\Xmax)}
 \xdef\Xmax{\Xmax}
 \xdef\Ymax{\Y}
}
\foreach \Layer/\X/\Col/\Miss/\Lab/\Count/\Content [count=\Y] in {#2}
{\node[anchor=south] at ({2*\Y},{\Xmax/2+0.1}) {\Layer};
 \foreach \m in {1,...,\X}
 {
  \ifnum\m=\Miss
   \node [neuron missing] (neuron-\Y-\m) at ({2*\Y},{\X/2-\m}) {};
  \else
   \node [circle,fill=\Col!50,minimum size=1cm] (neuron-\Y-\m) at 
  ({2*\Y},{\X/2-\m}) {\Content};
 \ifnum\Y=1
  \else
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\LastY}{\Y-1}
   \foreach \Z in {1,...,\LastX}
   {
    \ifnum\Z=\LastMiss
    \else
     \draw[->] (neuron-\LastY-\Z) -- (neuron-\Y-\m);
    \fi
    }
  \fi
 \fi
 \ifnum\Y=1
  \ifnum\m=\X
   \draw [overlay] (neuron-\Y-\m) -- (state);
  \else
   \ifnum\m=\Miss
   \else
    \draw [overlay] (neuron-\Y-\m) -- (state);
   \fi
  \fi
 \else
 \fi     
 }
 \xdef\LastMiss{\Miss}
 \xdef\LastX{\X}
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm,
>=stealth,font=\sffamily,nodes={align=center}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=T]
  \path  node[draw,minimum width=6em,minimum height=4em] (state) {State};
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=NN]
   \DrawNeuronalNetwork{Input Layer/5/green/4///,
     Hidden Layer/5/blue/4//11/,
     Output Layer/4/red/3//11/}
  \end{scope}
  \path (NN.south) node[below]{Estimated parameter\\ $\theta$};
  \path(NN.east) -- node[above]{Policy\\ $\Pi(\theta,a)$}++ (4em,0);
 \end{scope} 
 \node[fit=(T),label={[anchor=north west]north west:Agent},inner sep=1em,draw]
  (TF){};
 \node[below=3em of TF,draw,inner sep=1em] (Env) {Environment};
 \draw[<-] (TF.200) -- ++ (-1em,0) |- (Env.160) node[pos=0.45,right]{$r_t$};
 \draw[<-] (TF.180) -- ++ (-2em,0) |- (Env.180) node[pos=0.45,left]{$s_t$};
 \draw[->] (NN.east) -- ++ (7em,0)node[right]{$a_t$} |- (Env);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent start -- many thanks for sharing.